# Inkscape: problems with pattern along path

Tags: inkscape

When I make a path in Inkscape and create an object (triangle), I can't seem to get it on the path I created. [image: triangle and path]

This is what I get after pattern along path:
[image: pattern along path]

I never seem to get it on the path. Can anyone help me? I scaled the triangle before the pattern along path, when I don't change the dimensions of the triangle the pattern along path goes perfectly but I don't want an equilateral triangle.

Thanks for looking into my problem.
[image: original triangle on path]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you are going wrong to be honest.

Anyway this is for the latest Inkscape 1.0.  I'm going to do it using the new Path Effect named *Pattern Along a Path*

1. Basically I drew a triangle, and copied it
2. Selected the path I want to attach it to
3. Applied the Pattern Along a Path effect, chose *Link Path to Clipboard*, and set it to *Repeated* and that's it.

[image]
Click on the image to view larger